# My Plane bugs out in Unity after give too much Roll or Pitch Inputs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make an Airplane Simulator and when I Roll or pitch too much, the Airplane does this:
[text](https://youtu.be/mgvZLEjxzQM)
AOA is the angle of Attack which is the difference between the direction the plane is moving and the direction the plane is facing.
This is my Airplane Physics Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlanePhysics : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("General")]
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody rb;

    [Header("Values")]
    [SerializeField] private float velocity;
    [SerializeField] private int speed; //In m/s
    [SerializeField] private float altitude; //In m

    [Header("Thrust")]
    public float thrust = 0f;
    public float maxThrust = 1000f;

    [Header("Drag")]
    public float drag;
    [SerializeField] private float dragCoefficient;
    [SerializeField] private AnimationCurve dragCurve;
    [SerializeField] private float dragPower;

    [Header("Lift")]
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 moveDirection;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 faceDirection;
    [SerializeField] private float angleOfAttack;
    [SerializeField] private AnimationCurve liftCurve;
    [SerializeField] private float lift = 0f;
    [SerializeField] private float liftCoefficient = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private float liftPower;

    [Header("Induced Drag")]
    [SerializeField] private float inducedDrag;
    [SerializeField] private float inducedDragCoefficient;

    [Header("Enviroment")]
    public AnimationCurve airDensityAnimCurve;
    public float airDensity;


    private void Start()
    {
        //Calculations

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Calculations
        StartCoroutine(PhysicsSpeedCalculation());
        altitude = transform.position.y;
        speed = Mathf.RoundToInt(velocity * 50);
        //Thrust
        rb.AddRelativeForce(-transform.forward * thrust * airDensity);

        //Drag
        airDensity = airDensityAnimCurve.Evaluate(altitude);
        dragPower = dragCurve.Evaluate(angleOfAttack);
        drag = dragCoefficient * airDensity * ((speed * speed) / 2) * dragPower;
        rb.AddRelativeForce(-rb.velocity * drag);

        //Lift
        CalculateAOA();

        liftPower = liftCurve.Evaluate(angleOfAttack);
        lift = 0.5f * airDensity * liftCoefficient * liftPower * (speed * speed);
        rb.AddRelativeForce(lift * transform.up);

        //Induced Drag
        inducedDrag = speed * speed * inducedDragCoefficient * airDensity;
        rb.AddRelativeForce(inducedDrag * -transform.up);

    }

    IEnumerator PhysicsSpeedCalculation()
    {
        Vector3 lastposition = transform.position;
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
        velocity = ((lastposition - transform.position).magnitude);
    }

    private void CalculateAOA()
    {
        moveDirection = rb.velocity;
        faceDirection = transform.forward;

        Vector3 faceDirectionInPitch = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(faceDirection, transform.right);
        Vector3 moveDirectionInPitch = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(moveDirection, transform.right);

        angleOfAttack = Vector3.SignedAngle(-faceDirectionInPitch, moveDirectionInPitch, -transform.right);

        Debug.DrawLine(transform.TransformPoint(Vector3.zero), transform.TransformPoint(-faceDirectionInPitch));
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.TransformPoint(Vector3.zero), transform.TransformPoint(moveDirectionInPitch));

    }

}
```

And this my Script for the Controls:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlaneControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody rb;

    [Header("Pitch")]
    [SerializeField] private float pitchRate;

    [Header("Throttle")]
    [SerializeField] private PlanePhysics pP;
    [SerializeField] private Image throttleBar;
    private float percentThrust;

    private void Start()
    {
        percentThrust = (pP.maxThrust / 100) * 50f;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Pitch
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            rb.AddRelativeTorque(Vector3.right * pitchRate);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            rb.AddRelativeTorque(-Vector3.right * pitchRate);
        }

        //Roll
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            rb.AddRelativeTorque(Vector3.up * pitchRate);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            rb.AddRelativeTorque(-Vector3.up * pitchRate);
        }


        //Throttle
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            if (pP.thrust + (percentThrust * Time.deltaTime) < pP.maxThrust)
            {
                pP.thrust += percentThrust * Time.deltaTime;
                throttleBar.fillAmount = pP.thrust / pP.maxThrust;
            }
            else
            {
                pP.thrust = pP.maxThrust;
            }

        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {

            if (pP.thrust - (percentThrust * Time.deltaTime) > 0) 
            {
                pP.thrust -= percentThrust * Time.deltaTime;
                throttleBar.fillAmount = pP.thrust / pP.maxThrust;
            }
            else
            {
                pP.thrust = 0f;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I tried Debug.Log, trying around with center of mass, but nothing seems to work...